anger with something (rather than someone)?
I know that anger comes with the preposition "with" while discussing anger directed at someone, (e.g. "your anger with your unbearable boss"); but should we use the same preposition while discussing anger directed at something, such as "your anger with the new compensation model" or "your anger with the new working conditions"? And if not, which preposition should be used?

ODE courtesy of Google has '"she could barely restrain her anger at this comment".

Maybe frustration, or even exasperation, but anger seems extreme, unless you're beating your lawnmower with a sledgehammer or something like that. Then you're just mad, which is fine, but in a crazy way.


I know that anger comes with the preposition "with" while discussing anger directed at someone,

This is not so.
*(e.g. "your anger with your unbearable boss")
Anger collocates with "towards" and "at"
It is "angry" that collocates with "with": She was angry with herself for forgetting the key."

There's also "angry at" someone

And anger over something or towards someone.

As for the collocation of propositions after the term anger there are a few options as suggested by Oxford Collocation Dictionary:

PREP. in ~ He raised his voice in anger. | with ~ His face was flushed with anger. | ~ against her feelings of anger against the murderer | ~ at I felt a sudden anger at his suggestion. | ~ over There is much anger over plans to close the hospital. | ~ towards her anger towards her parents.

Regarding your specific request with, towards, at and over can   be used.
You can find usage examples from Ngram also.

A better answer as it includes supporting references.

When referring to abstract conditions, it's common to use either "over" or "about".

I'm angry about the poor pay for public school teachers.


OP asks about 'anger', already well addressed.
